# MySQL db in utf8_general_ci, connection in utf8mb4_general_ci, how to deal with "Illegal mix of collations"?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, utf8mb4

I have a MySQL database that is all in `utf8_general_ci` charset.

The only exception is the field `subject` in the `newsletter` table that has charset `utf8mb4_general_ci`.

This is done to allow storing emoji utf8 chars.

When via a php script I establish a connection to the db I run

```
mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8mb4')
```

this way I am also able to display the utf8 emoji chars.

So, my website exposes urls like this:

```
https://example.org/my-slug
```

that internally are translated in a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM page WHERE slug = 'my-slug'
```

The problem is that sometimes (expecially from Bing, Microsoft IPs) I receive visits to urls like

```
https://example.org/my-slug%0cL%ce%0c%cd%cc%8c%8d%0cL
```

that originates this query

```
SELECT * FROM page WHERE slug = 'my-slug^LL<CE>^L<CD>̌<8D>^LL'
```

that fails with the error

```
PHP User Warning - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
```

Is there a way solve this error:

- without modifying the query
- without changing the all database charset from `utf8_general_ci` to `utf8mb4_general_ci`
- without losing the ability to save and display utf8 emoji

?

Answer (score 0):

`%0cL%ce%0c%cd%cc%8c%8d%0cL` is gibberish that does not map to meaningful information in any character set that I have tested.

Shift-JIS, for example, interprets it as `Lﾃﾍﾌ訣L`; does that make sense in Japanese?  Latin1: `LÃÍÌŒL`.  It breaks utf8 and utf8mb4.  Koi8r and koi8u`Lцмл▄█L`.

The hex for that string has an unusually large number of `C`:  `0c4cc30ccdcc8c8d0c4c`

If you must deal with such strings, then I suggest you use `VARBINARY` or `BLOB` (depending on size) for the column datatype.  This has the drawback of not doing case folding, but maybe that is not relevant.

Comment: With the same gibberish url, the error does not occur if I set the connection charset to `mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8')`